# How to set defaultParams with a recompose, lifecycle HOC?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recompose

I have the following recompose, lifecycle HOC:

```
import { lifecycle } from 'recompose';

export function myHoc(title) {
    return lifecycle({
        componentDidMount() {
           console.log(title)
        }
    });
}

export default myHoc;
```

I use this HOC in my components like so:

```
export default myHoc('x')(PageName);
```

What I would like to do is be able to use the HOC with params like so:

```
export default myHoc({
   param1: "somevalue",
   param2: "somevalue",
   param3: "somevalue",
})(PageName);
```

And then in the HOC, have defaults set for param1 and params 2&3 be required or an error would occur.

Is this possible with recompose lifecycle? Thanks

Comment: Or maybe there is a better way to pass props/params/properties to the HOC? I would think the HOC should throw an error if 1 or more of the required params are missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use parameter destructuring in the HOC function.  You can throw an Error if you want the code to error out if required parameters aren't provided.

```
export function myHoc({param1 = 'default', param2, param3}) {
    if (!param2) {
      throw new Error('param2 is required');
    }

    if (!param3) {
      throw new Error('param3 is required');
    }

    return lifecycle({
        componentDidMount() {
           console.log(param2);
        }
    });
}
```